# Convergence of sequence implies convergence of supremum of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is part of the proof for the Donsker Theorem form Mörters Brownian Motion. There, the authors state, that for any sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=1$$
it is implied that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{0\leq k\leq n}\left|\frac{a_k-k}{n}\right|=0.$$

Intuitively, it seems clear. If $a_n/n$ converges to $1$, than the the absolute of the biggest deviation of $a_n$ from the diagonal n should be going to zero. But i have difficulties to see, how one would proof that formally. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3649435/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%5Csup_%7B0%5Cleq%20k%5Cleq%20n%7D%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7Ba_k-k%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%7C%3D0.%24)

Comment: I believe if you assume for contradiction the latter limit is strictly positive, you would get a subsequence $\lbrace a_{n_s}\rbrace_s$ such that $\lim_{s\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n_s}-n_s}{n_s}| = c>0$, which would contradict the first limit.